# colResizable can use in nested table?

Tags: jquery, resize

So,Like as title, colResizable can use in nested table or what am i miss something? It don't work when i called `.colResizable().`

```
$(document).ready(function () {          
            $("#dynamicTable").colResizable({ 
                liveDrag:true,     
                gripInnerHtml:"<div class='grip'></div>",     
                draggingClass:"dragging",     
                resizeMode:'fit'    
        });            
        });
```

This is my body

```
<table style="width: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border-spacing: 0">
 <tr>
    <td></td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td style="border-left: 1px solid silver; border-right: 1px solid silver; vertical-align: top; height: 800px">
        <table id="dynamicTable" style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Testing 1
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table style="width: 100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Testing 2
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </td>
                <td>
                     Testing 3
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I googled one day for that and  i found nothing useful for me. Please let me known if you have any advice why it dont work.Thanks.

Comment: Could you please create a jsFiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r6y53b0e/  This my jsFiddle.Thanks

Comment: Would you mind adding the JavaScripts? I get this Error on the jsFiddle: TypeError: $(...).colResizable is not a function

Comment: @Chris Ohh! sorry i use colResizable-1.6.js file also .Please let me known how can i add this file to jsFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/r6y53b0e/2/ This my update link.Thanks

Comment: @Chris This link will work https://jsfiddle.net/r6y53b0e/3/ .

Comment: On the right side you can add external Resources. When you want to search for external Resources, you can search for something like "jquery colResizable cdn". CDN stands for Content Delivery Network and is supported nearly everywhere. Should then looks like https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.colresizable/1.3/colResizable.min.js

Comment: i don't get it to work anyway. i added the source but the error "TypeError: $(...).colResizable is not a function" still exists. to figure out if there is an Error or not, use the Browser intern Debug Tools.